# ¿Como colocar un alias a cada fila resultante de UNION en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Teniendo la siguiente tabla:

```
Productos
_______________
id_producto
nombre_producto
tipo_especial
fecha_inclusion
```

> Quisiera obtener la cuenta de productos condicionando sean o no tipo
>   especial, colocandole un alias a cada fila resultante, con el fin de luego
>   poder trabajar por separado los resultados evitando hacer una consulta
>   para cada tipo_especial.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), nombre_producto, tipo_especial
FROM productos
WHERE tipo_especial = 1
AND fecha_inclusion "2018-03-12"

UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*), nombre_producto
FROM productos
WHERE tipo_especial = 2
AND fecha_inclusion "2018-03-12"
```

Resultado esperado:

```
                         | COUNT(*) | NOMBRE_PRODUCTO
producto_tipo_especial_1 |    1     | queso         
producto_tipo_especial_2 |    5     | jamon
```

Resultado obtenido

```
| COUNT(*) | NOMBRE_PRODUCTO
|    1     | queso
|    5     | jamon
```

Comment: @gbianchi estoy acomodando la pregunta

Comment: no alcanza con agregar un string adelante como en todas las bases de datos? "producto_tipo_especial_1 " as descripcion?

Comment: @gbianchi como agrego esa string?

Comment: select  "producto_tipo_especial_1 " as descripcion, count(*), etc etc etc.. asi no funciona?

Comment: ah.. y el problema que estas teniendo con las respuestas es que llamas ALIAS a algo que no es un ALIAS, vos queres agregar un campo con un texto fijo a las filas de tu consulta. ALIAS se usa para renombrar a los campos de una DB

Comment: @gbianchi, gracias estas en lo correcto, publica la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero y principal, ALIAS en base de datos se utiliza para los nombres de los campos. Por lo tanto, cuando uno habla de ALIAS, esta diciendo que se le van a cambiar los nombres en los campos de una consulta, lo que usualmente se hace agregando `AS nombrecampo`.

Tu problema es que en realidad queres identificar unequivocamente las filas que devuelve cada select de tu union.

Para eso, deberias agregar dentro de tu consulta una cadena fija que se va a repetir por cada fila del select.

```
SELECT  "producto_tipo_especial_1" as descripcion, COUNT(*), nombre_producto, tipo_especial
FROM productos
WHERE tipo_especial = 1
AND fecha_inclusion "2018-03-12"

UNION 
SELECT "producto_tipo_especial_2" as descripcion, COUNT(*), nombre_producto
FROM productos
WHERE tipo_especial = 2
AND fecha_inclusion "2018-03-12"
```

Fijate que en la cadena fija que puse, si le agregue un ALIAS. Los campos tienen alias, las filas tiene datos...

Answer (score 2):

en MySQL se hace anteponiendo la palabra clave AS

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cantidad, nombre_producto AS 'Nombre del Producto', tipo_especial AS 'Tipo Especial'
FROM productos
WHERE tipo_especial = 1
AND fecha_inclusion "2018-03-12"
```

si la palabra que quieres usar como alias es una sola puedes ponerla directamente, si son varias debes hacerlo con comillas

Comment: El alias deberia ser para ambos resultados de manera que pueda saber a cual le corresponde la cuenta y el nombre del producto.

Comment: no entiendo a que te refieres con "debe ser para ambos resultados"

Answer (score 2):

Saludos lo unico que tienes que hacer es usar AS y entre comillas el nombre que quieres tenga dicha columna

```
SELECT COUNT(*), nombre_producto AS 'Nombre del Producto', tipo_especial AS 'Tipo Especial'
FROM productos
WHERE tipo_especial = 1
AND fecha_inclusion "2018-03-12"

UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*), nombre_producto AS 'Nombre del Producto'
FROM productos
WHERE tipo_especial = 2
AND fecha_inclusion "2018-03-12"
```

Comment: El alias deberia ser para ambos resultados de manera que pueda saber a cual le corresponde la cuenta y el nombre del producto.